# Where is application data for the Ubuntu Touch core apps stored in Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch

I am looking to sync data for my Ubuntu Touch apps in Trusty Tahr, and wanted to know where to find their application data. E.G., what is the file location for Browser bookmarks, Notes, and Calendar appointments data?

Answer (score 0):

The touch apps are designed to be confined, mostly.

The browser is storing data in `~/.local/share/webbrowser-app/` and Notes stores its data in `~/.local/share/com.ubuntu.notes/`. Calendar events on the other hand, I think are stored via the `evolution-data-server` so if you want to sync the directory for Calendar events, I think it is `~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/` for the local system calendar.